# Thousands of incoming HEAD requests - best way to handle with EC2?

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-2.4

I had unusually high https traffic recently from a couple of IP address with agents masquerading as Windows clients.  I blocked the range via 'deny' inside of .htaccess (Apache 2.4)

I'm still getting nearly 1,000 HEAD requests per second, which httpd is correctly responding with a 403...but the incoming pings are still coming.

I'm on an AWS EC2 and was looking at options there (aside from going to WAF/load balancer, etc).  Should I be configuring a network firewall for this, or is there some other simple way to halt this traffic at the ingress to the EC2 instance?

(edit) I did just now add that subnet to the EC2 network ACL inbound rules (deny), and it seems to be working...maybe that is the right answer?

Comment: Why are you looking for options besides some of the best ones? I’d say Cloudfront, WAF, and load balancers are all requirements for instance-backed public web sites, **especially** if there are any forms and/or database back ends. If you’re asking about a "network firewall", that’s what a WAF is, more or less.

Comment: Are you sure the traffic is malicious and not just a misconfigured client? Occam's razor applies.

Comment: I am simply looking at the traffic and not trying to figure out the intent.  HEAD requests on several hundred disparate pages seems like something a little more than a client issue.  Also, this is the second 'wave' of these incidents in the last three months.  I am going to stand up a load balancer and WAF in AWS in front of the EC2, with rate-limiting rules.  I can't continue to get surprised by this sort of thing.

Comment: @ToddWilcox agree, but I needed something immediately (in the moment); certainly am now looking at dialing in the correct solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest way to block a small number of IP addresses on AWS is NACLs (network access control lists). NACLs are ideal because they have both ALLOW and DENY rules, which let you DENY a few IPs then ALLOW a large range - usually 0.0.0.0/0.

Security groups, on the other hand, only have allow rules. If you wanted to exclude one IP you'd have to go to a lot of trouble to craft a whole set of allows that would make up all IPs you want less the one you don't want, which would be a *lot* of rules.

If the traffic you don't want is from many IPs you'd be better off with AWS WAF or an external service such as CloudFlare. CloudFlare has free and paid plans, their free plan is sufficient for many personal servers, and their paid plans are pretty good value. NB: I have no association with CloudFlare, I just like their service.

Fail2ban is another option. The downside of this or similar options is you still need to use bandwidth and CPU to deny these requests. I prefer to use a CDN to prevent them reaching the server at all.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  I know I have to move to a WAF.  I was looking at CloudFlare but moving DNS to them might be tricky for me; I run vanity nameservers at Route53 and have hundreds of records due to a Wordpress multisite installation.  I will try to stick with something inside of AWS, first.

Comment: Why network ACL over security group(s)?

Comment: @ToddWilcox I've expanded my answer significantly to answer your question. Short answer though - NACLs have ALLOW and DENY rules so it's simple to deny a small number of IPs, security groups are ALLOW only.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the OS you're running on your ec2 instance, you could install [fail2ban](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban) and write a small script for it that checks your access_log for HEAD requests, blocking any IP that issues too many of them.

I linked to the `fail2ban` repo, but most (all?) distributions make it available via package manager these days.

The advantage of `fail2ban` is it works automatically once set up, and it unblocks IPs after a configurable time, which may or may not help with users complaining they accidentially blocked themselves and request an unblock.

[Here](https://pipo.blog/articles/20210915-fail2ban-apache-dos) is an example of someone using it to filter out web clients that run too many `GET` requests on `robots.txt`. The gist of it, adapted to OP's needs, is a pattern config file `jail-d/apache-head.conf`

```
[apache-head]
enabled  = true
port     = http,https
filter   = apache-too-many-heads
logpath  = /var/www/*/logs/access.log
datepattern = %%d/%%b/%%Y:%%H:%%M:%%S %%z
maxretry = 300
findtime = 5m
bantime  = 1h
```

and a `filter.d/apache-too-many-heads.conf`

```
# Fail2Ban filter to scan Apache access.log for DoS attacks

[INCLUDES]
before = common.conf

[Definition]
# Option:  failregex
# Notes.:  regex to match HEAD requests in the logfile
#          The host must be matched by a group named "host". The tag "<HOST>" 
#          can be used for standard IP/hostname matching and is only an alias for
#          (?:::f{4,6}:)?(?P<host>[\w\-.^_]+)
# Values:  TEXT
failregex = ^<HOST> .*"HEAD

# Option:  ignoreregex
# Notes.:  regex to ignore. If this regex matches, the line is ignored.
# Values:  TEXT
#
ignoreregex =
```

This would find hosts that have more than 300 (maxretry) HEAD (failregex) requests in 5 minutes (findtime) and use `iptables`/`nftables` to block their IP for one hour (bantime).

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out.

Comment: I just looked at it; the readme seems to indicate that it is used to prevent multiple login attempts.  That's good, but I also need a rate-limiting control.  E.g. an IP address requesting more than X number of pages within a specified time-slice.  I believe Cloudfront or AWS WAF will do this.

Comment: @CC, you can use any "more than X log file entries in Y time" pattern with fail2ban. [Here](https://pipo.blog/articles/20210915-fail2ban-apache-dos)'s an example with apache; that one looks for too many `GET` requests, but if you switch out the `GET` for `HEAD` in the example you're probably 90% there.

Comment: thank you for that, I will look into this more carefully.  I suppose the trick here would be to figure out how to block these 'bad' requesting IP addresses, but at the same time allow 'friendly' higher-than-a-human rate requests (e.g. Google's indexing bot).  Maybe the 'ignoreregex' option is how to handle that.  I am still going to figure out the AWS load balancer and WAF setup, though...I want to learn how to do it and I believe it's a longer term solution : )